# LinkOpen::linke: Could not find MathLink executable. >>

Tags: mathematica

When I'm using Mathematica 8 and try to import a file I get this error: `LinkOpen::linke: Could not find MathLink executable. >>` and the place I tried to input the file to is just saying `Null`.

I have been able to import files into Mathematica earlier, but it has suddenly stopped working.

I'm using Mac OS X 10.7.2

Comment: On Windows, or OS X?

Comment: @slhck on OS X 10.7.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By replacing files inside Mathematica.app (8.0.0) with the same files from the Mathematica trial (8.0.4), I found that the problem was the file

```
Mathematica.app/SystemFiles/Kernel/SystemResources/MacOSX-x86-64/Converters.mx
```

I have uploaded the working `Converters.mx` [here](http://cl.ly/DMl1) in case someone else gets this problem too.

Answer (score 1):

I expect your Mathematica installation is broken.  Can you try to reinstall it?

Mathematica uses helper programs (separate processes) to import or export certain file types.  I believe this error indicates that it cannot find the helper program's executable to launch.  Since these come with the Mathematica installation, the only explanation I can find is that your installation got corrupted.

Note: Most of these executables are in `SystemFiles/Converters/Binaries` within the Mathematica installation directory.